# Get historical stock level from Quickbooks TradeGecko API

Tags: api, quickbooks

I am using TradeGecko API (docs: https://developer.tradegecko.com/docs.html) to get my shop's data. The API comes with a StockLevel resource, but it only return the stock level at the moment, not in the past. I want to see how the stock level changes over time. Any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tradegecko API is sunsetting at the time of writing this comment. But if anyone needs this, I went to Intelligence > Reporting > Inventory > Stock history. Pick a timeframe and stock location to download the historical data.
I also used Python Selenium for automatic download the data into my email, then used the Gmail API to get the csv link and process the data.